# Apart from Brahmarishi Vishwamitra any people from Kshatriyas became rishis?

Tags: rishi, varna, war, kshatriya, tapasya

Vishwamitra was originally a rajanya and then achieved enlightenment. I take it that he achieved  Brahmin Varna.
Are there any more examples with references?